# How to Start SharePoint 2013 Workflows on Selected Items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I want to edit multiple items on a Sharepoint list with a workflow. But when i select more then one item the workflow button is grayed out.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Nagarajan's answer below is just ridiculous.  If that's the way to accomplish this seemingly simple task... that's insane.

Comment: it works but consumes more manual effort. Have to find easier way

Comment: I dont thik there is a easier way. You can try to update the list items via powershell and set the workflow to run on edit items too.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a direct option to Start workflow for multiple selected items on a single click, but you may try this workaround.

1. Create a view that will have only the items you want to trigger
   workflow (apply appropriate filters)
2. Create a dummy column of any simple data type, lets have a 'Single Line of text' column
3. Add this column to the view created
4. Set the Workflow to Run whenever an item is edited
5. Open the view in quick edit/ datasheet format
6. Update the first item's dummy column with a dummy value (Say A) and drag the value to the entire list of items in the view
7. The workflow will be triggereed for all the items in the view
8. Finally delete the dummy column from the list